# Using metatype in closure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metaprogramming, metatype

Is it possible to use metatype in closures? The simplest example I came up with does not work

```
let type = String.self
let closure = { () -> type in
    return type.init()
}
```

Compiler complains at the second line about the `type`:

```
Use of undeclared type 'type'
```

I wonder is there a way to make it work?

If you are wondering the real use case is in dependency injection where I could inject related types in a `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, I removed the return type to make it implicit and it worked. Probably it is some kind of swift compiler bug. End result:

```
let type = String.self
let closure = { () in
    return type.init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then having type as constant, you can simply use generic constraint and then you just have to figure out how compiler can infer your type.

```
func makeSomething<T: YourProtocol>(...) {
    let closure = { () -> T in
        return T()
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see how it can be used in my example